# Pages returned by alloc_pages Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

- Are pages allocated using `alloc_pages` in kernel, also mapped for user use if that's relevant, ensured to be pinned and will not be swapped out to disk?
- Is the page's address returned by `alloc_pages` function is dma address? that is, is it the same address type that hardware device could access through the dma?

Answer (score 0):

> Are pages allocated using alloc_pages in kernel, also mapped for user
>   use if that's relevant, ensured to be pinned and will not be swapped
>   out to disk?

alloc_pages() allocate pages both for kernel and user space, depends on who's calling it. Pages  used by user space.If it is anonymous(user stack or heap) page, then it can be swapped out.

> Is the page's address returned by alloc_pages function is
>   dma address? that is, is it the same address type that hardware device
>   could access through the dma?

Not necessary.You have to specify a flag tell alloc_pages() what kind of pages you want(eg.__GFP_DMA or __GFP_DMA32 for dma address).

Comment: Thank you.
Regarding your first answer: I just allocated in Kernel space and through mmap mapped vma to this kernel page. And so user will be able to use it as an array or whatever. Does that mean that the physical page allocated in Kernel might be swapped out?

Comment: Yes, I might be swapped out.

Comment: Even if using the flag GFP_DMA?
If you answer is yes then what is this flag anyway for? As I understand, and I definitely might be wrong, this flag is used to allocated memory so that hardware devices will be able to access it through the DMA. To be able to achieve that pages have to be pinned. What Am I missing?

Comment: You are right, DMA pages can not be swapped, or the device can't find a place to do data transmit.What I said might be swapped in last comment,  just refer to pages that are mmaped to userspace, this is not a guarantee that pages pinned to the memory.

Comment: So just to sum it up and make sure please I understand correctly.
If I allocate pages in Kernel mode using alloc_pages with flag GFP_DMA and then map them for user-space usage through remap_pfn_range it is guaranteed that these pages are pinned into memory and therefore dma device will be always able to access memory through physical address?